# Running original xbox game in a virtual machine

Tags: xbox-360, emulation, medal-of-honor-rising-sun

I have an ISO file for [Medal of Honor: Rising Sun](https://archive.org/details/MedalofHonorRisingSun_USA_redump_20322).

I am wondering if it is possible to use Oracle's VirtualBox to run the game in a virtual machine and use my Xbox 360 controller with the receiver to play the game.
 I am also thinking of downloading the Xbox 360 OS online (since rising sun is supported on the xbox 360). Is what I am wanting to do will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not right now, no. Xbox 360 emulation is still very premature and it is not yet possible to play the majority of retail games from start to finish.

Besides, VirtualBox won't be able to run the Xbox 360 OS either since VB only virtualizes x86 and x64 platforms. Xbox 360 uses the powerpc architecture.

Comment: Well thanks anyway. I am looking into Xenia right now.